# Javascript postMessage

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

How does a browser like chrome exchange data between a window and its IFrame (window being on 1 domain name and IFrame loads content from another domain name)?

My question is, how the browser can send a JS object to an IFrame? Is it done with HTTP request or some other network protocol?

I can't see it in Chrome's network tab, that's why I was wondering

Comment: The data doesn't need to be sent over the network, it is already in the browser, it just needs to be made available to one context or another.

Comment: @Titus so even though they are on different servers, it doesnt matter still right? Thank you though because even Mozilla docs didn't explain this clearly or even at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR;** because the parent window can directly get the iframe's `Window`, the browser can use an offline, event-based communication protocol to communicate.

A network protocol is not needed in this case as the parent window can directly  reference the embedded iframe's `Window` object (using `HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow`, which can then be used to listen to `MessageEvent`s).

When the parent window calls `otherWindow.postMessage(...)`, that message is [`serialized internally`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#serializable-objects) and passed to the `otherWindow`, which automatically deserializes the object so long as the iframe's `Window` is listening for `MessageEvent`s by having registered an **event listener** for `message` like so:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // passed offline using serialization algorithm specified in spec (2.9.1)
    console.log(event.data); // contains deserialized object
});
```

Comment: Still though I can see this 100% clearly like you explained (greatly btw) if both parent window and Iframe window are on the same domain, but since the IFrame is in a different domain, how does the parent window is send from 1 server to another without any networking? or say if the parent is sending a window object, does this object not being sent to server but rather to different JS context of the loaded document as a whole?

Comment: One of the reasons `postMessage` was introduced was to allow cross-origin communication, so communicating with a different-domain iframe will work the same as with a same-domain iframe (unless the embedded iframe disallows being embedded). There is no server communication needed. What you might see is domain `a.com` sending a message to `b.com` using `postMessage`, and then `b.com` sending a message to its server based on the received message, but `postMessage` in itself will not go through any servers -- it is all offline in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You cant pass a JavaScript object to an `iFrame`, but you can still access elements from `iFrame` like below:

```
$('#iframeId').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#element');
```

It will access the element (suppose a hidden field) and set the value which you need to pass and use it in your `iFrame` content.

Comment: You can transfer objects between iFrames and the main window. That can be done using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). The OP is asking about that kind of data transfer.

Comment: @Titus that will be correct answer for this question, thanks

Comment: `You cant pass a JavaScript object to an iFrame` is not correct, you can send object to Iframe with postMessage.It is not just about reading what is in the Iframe, you can send it objects too

Comment: @IbrahimD. Yes I agree with you, it is a n another way to pass values

Answer (score -2):

should be able to read the globals.

```
<script>var masterOfTheUniverse = "He-Man";</script>
```

should be visible from anywhere in and out the iFrame.

Or, you can use the browser storage

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("masterOfTheUniverse", "He-Man");
// Retrieve
localStorage.getItem("masterOfTheUniverse");
```

Comment: localStorage only use for same domain